# Crawl streaming tweets and historical tweets with python

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler

I want to crawl streaming twitter data with python for a search query. One questions here: is it true that data I will collect is generated right from the time I run the script?

Also, how to crawl tweets in the past given day? Is is possible I can get access to all the tweets in that day?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to get old tweets and streaming tweets of a particular user or for a search query?

Comment: For a search query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes **it's true** that if you do streaming it will be collected **from the moment you start that service**.

So what you can do is **get old tweets** by another mechanism, here is a [**github repo**](https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python) , it will give the result in CSV format and you can specify range of dates for that search too.

And you can simultaneously run the streaming service which will provide you tweets from that point forward.